# Mongodb aggregate to find if a user is in any other user's follower list

Tags: mongodb

I collected followers list and friends list for n number of users from twitter and stored them in mongodb.

Here is a sample document:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("561d6f8986a0ea57e51ec95c"),
  "status": "True",
  "UserId": "1489245878",
  "followers": [
    "1566382441",
    "1155774331"
  ],
  "followersCount": 2,
  "friendsCount": 5,
  "friends": [
    "1135511478",
    "998082481",
    "565321118",
    "848123988",
    "343334562"
  ]
}
```

I wanted to know within my collection, are there any userids that are also in the followers list of some other documents. Lets say we have user "a", now i would like to know if user "a" is in the followers list of any other document within the same collection. I'm not sure how to do this. In case if we have, i would like to project the userid and the _id of the document that has the userid within the followers list.

Comment: Check out the documentation at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. it helps if i have to look for just one user. I'm trying to have it more general. like list all the userids and the document ids that have the userid in the their followers list

Comment: No problem! Depending on what language you are using as your driver to the db, you can always just query for all userids from all documents and store those in a list.  Then query all documents that contain any of those userids in the followers list. This will probably not be the most efficient solution however.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use aggregate function like below to get this result.

```
db.getCollection('your_collection").aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "followers": "1566382441"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "followers": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$followers"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "followers": "1566382441"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$followers",
      "ids": {
        "$addToSet": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "userId": "$_id",
      "ids": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

I am using only a sample of your data. You can add your list of users for whom you are trying to filter in both stages of `"$match"`. Just see if this helps.

P.S: I know its been a long time since you asked this question! But you know, its never late!